# Calling an asynchronous method (getNotificationSettings) in the onAppear() method becomes nil - SwiftUI MVVM

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `NotificationsManager` class to manage all notification-related code, including the code to check if the user has turned off local notifications. I use this class in multiple parts of my code and it works fine, my issue is that I want to call the `getNotificationSettings` through the `NotificationsManager` class in the onAppear method in SwiftUI but it always becomes nil. I know it has to do something with the fact that the `getNotificationSettings` is an asynchronous method, but I'm not sure how to call it and get the result on the onAppear method.

In the following code, `notificationManager.notificationAuthorizationStatus` always becomes `nil` in the `onAppear` method.

**Any idea how can I call the `reloadAuthorizationStatus()` method in the `onAppear` method in `SwiftUI` and right after check the `notificationAuthorizationStatus` property?**

#### NotificationsManager Class

```
class NotificationsManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published private(set) var notificationAuthorizationStatus: UNAuthorizationStatus?

    func reloadAuthorizationStatus() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.notificationAuthorizationStatus = settings.authorizationStatus
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var notificationManager = NotificationsManager()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                // textFields...
            }
            .onAppear(){
                notificationManager.reloadAuthorizationStatus() 
                // here the notificationAuthorizationStatus is always nil              
                switch notificationManager.notificationAuthorizationStatus{
                case .denied:
                    hasAuthorized = false
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I add a 1-second delay before calling the `notificationAuthorizationStatus` it works but I know this is not right since sometimes it may take longer than just a second to get the results.

#### Call with a 1 Second Delay

Works but I don't feel it's the right thing to do

```
.onAppear(){
    notificationManager.reloadAuthorizationStatus()                
    let secondsDelay = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: secondsDelay){
        switch notificationManager.notificationAuthorizationStatus{
        case .denied:
            hasAuthorized = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are listening to changes in the NotificationsManager. This means you could still call reloadAuthorizationStatus() in onAppear(), but then, assuming hasAuthorized is used to display or hide UI elements, you could code your logic using the notificationAuthorizationStatus directly. Your UI will change according to the value of notificationAuthorizationStatus. By doing so, you are not dependent on how long reloadAuthorizationStatus() takes to return an answer.

Comment: look up `completion handlers` and `closures`  for your `reloadAuthorizationStatus` function. Hint: `completion: @escaping(....)`

Comment: I suggest to NotificationsManager Class as a Singleton, because your DispatchQueue is running simultaneously with onAppear and I think you will face this kind of issue in most of the method until it is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an asynchronous function, you have to wait until it has finished before you can use any of its results. Using a `completion` handler is a common approach to do just that. So try this approach:

```
func reloadAuthorizationStatus(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {  // <-- here
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.notificationAuthorizationStatus = settings.authorizationStatus
            completion(true) // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

and in `ContentView`

```
    .onAppear {
        notificationManager.reloadAuthorizationStatus { isDone in  // <-- here
            switch notificationManager.notificationAuthorizationStatus{
            case .denied:
                hasAuthorized = false
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Another approach is to leave your code as is, and use this `.onReceive`:

```
.onReceive(notificationManager.notificationAuthorizationStatus.publisher) { status in
    switch status{
    case .denied:
        hasAuthorized = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
.onAppear {
    notificationManager.reloadAuthorizationStatus()
}
```

Comment: I need to have a better understanding of completion handlers and closures. Thanks a lot for your help.